# Computing $e^{At}$ for Complex Eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Here is the matrix

$A  =  \begin{pmatrix}
-1 &-1\\
   1&0
\end{pmatrix}
$

I want to calculate $e^{At}$ for the given matrix, my main issue is that the problems which I have solved in the past usually involve real Eigenvalues, but here the eigenvalues are complex

$\lambda_1  = \dfrac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$, $\lambda_2 = \dfrac{-1 - i\sqrt{3}}{2}$

I don't understand how to proceed in such a scenario.

Any hints will be helpful.

Comment: The youtuber 3blue1brown made a video on this if you’re interested https://youtu.be/O85OWBJ2ayo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a$ and $b$ are real, Euler's formula gives
$$
\exp\bigl((a + bi)t\bigr) = e^{at}(\cos bt + i\sin bt),
$$
after which you can proceed just as in the case of real eigenvalues.